# Does running all tests in an org impact actual real functionality? Should I not run all tests in production daily?

Tags: apex, unit-test, deployment, test-automation, apextestrunresult

For years I was under the assumption that running all tests in an org does not impact actual functionality. At most, it may somewhat impact performance...

Every night I run all tests in our UAT environment to try and spot any test failures as soon as possible as we have multiple projects deploying to UAT regularly. We have one project where they are trying to do testing at night and are seeing errors such as "unable to lock row". They claim this is because there are tests running during their functional testing and it is messing with real functional user testing. Is this possible? I also run all tests in production after every release. Is running all tests in production breaking actual functionality? Is it not safe to run tests in production? I was under the assumption tests run in their own context with their own test data (all our tests generate test data). Why when tests are running are they unable to create users in UAT?

Thanks!

Comment: `Unable to lock row` is a common regtest error if parallel tests are being run and setup objects (like users) are being mocked - I'd toss this one back to the complaining team

Comment: So they actually opened a case with Salesforce support, where the support agent said if tests are being run, it can impact real data. The issues arent that tests are failing, its that real data is being affected - ex: creating a new user is being prevented while tests are being run. Our tests don't run in parallel they execute one at a time, and they all use mock data. So I'm not sure whether Salesforce support is wrong or this is a real thing. I'm assuming the code they're testing is just buggy and they're blaming test classes for it.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, running tests at any time should not impact real performance. This is explained in the [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm) documentation. However, some caveats apply.

Any production data that can be accessed during unit test runtime can be locked during a unit test run. This means that tests running with SeeAllData=true enabled can lock real accounts, contacts, opportunities, etc for the duration of the test. Further, using a real user, which is always allowed in unit tests (they are not isolated) can prevent that user record from being edited during the unit test execution, possibly including assigning Ownership for records being used by the unit tests.

Notably, using `System.runAs(user)` with a real user can impact the ability to modify that user record. Similarly, let's imagine SeeAllData=true and a real Account is queried, and a unit test contact is created. Because of the behavior described in [Avoiding Deadlocks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_deadlocks.htm), the real Account would be locked because of the unit test Contact, which would be released at the end of the unit test.

However, most likely, what they're doing is all working off of some test account, and trying to create Contacts, Cases, Opportunities, etc all at the same time. They're most likely locking each other up, rather than the unit tests affecting them. A fair number of Salesforce users probably don't know that just creating a Contact locks the Account for the duration of the transaction.

There're two articles of interest here: [Avoid Account Data Skew for Peak Performance](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/04/avoid-account-data-skew-for-peak-performance) and [Ownership Data Skew](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_group_membership_data_skew.htm). Either of these conditions can cause issues while functional testing. Make sure they're not loading a single Account with tens of thousands of records, and they're not creating tens of thousands of records owned by a single user. These can cause problems.

So, if you're following the unit testing best practices, it is most likely that this team are themselves creating the record-lock problems, rather than your unit tests. It's very difficult to get unit tests to interfere with production functional testing on purpose, much less by accident, assuming you're following the guidelines, such as always creating test data for every unit test.

Unfortunately, all of this requires more detailed analysis than what we have here. This is one of those situations where, if Support has an answer like that, you probably want to get a consultant or other expert to work with the testing team to get to the bottom of things. There're so many variables involved it would be hard to diagnose this in a non-descript question like this.

The only real advice I can offer at this point is to make sure they're not assigning records to users that are used in the unit tests (e.g. the Admin running the tests, or users being used by System.runAs), and to make sure they're not accidentally stepping on each other's work by using the same parent account at the same time. These are the two most likely scenarios, and both are easily preventable by using a different user and/or account for each test.